# How to run a cron job for edX notifier digest

Tags: cron, edx

I am trying to write a bash script that would be run by a daily cron job as a specific user ('notifier').

1. Entry in the crontab and the bash script

   ```
   crontab -u notifier -e

   53 09 * * * /edx/app/notifier/not.sh
   ```

   The contents of the script which I placed in the home directory of my user ('notifier) are as follows:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   SHELL=/bin/bash
   PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

   cd "$(dirname "$0")"
   DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "tomorrow"`

   /edx/app/notifier/virtualenvs/notifier/bin/python /edx/app/notifier/src/manage.py forums_digest --to_datetime=$DATE
   ```

   This does not work as expected, however.
2. Below are the individual steps that I successfully run manually

   ```
   sudo -H -u notifier bash
   cd
   DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "tomorrow"`
   /edx/app/notifier/virtualenvs/notifier/bin/python /edx/app/notifier/src/manage.py forums_digest --to_datetime=$DATE
   ```

How can I run notifier digest as a cron job?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Is `/edx/app` really the home directory of this user? Are you attempting to use a virtualenv without running its `activate` script (or are you using a nonstandard venv which doesn't require one)? Conversely, do your manual steps work after you `deactivate` (or whatever)?

Comment: This is looking more like a Python question than a Bash question or a Cron question anyway.

Comment: This seems a directory issue. I have been experimenting with a lot in the last few days. I can run the steps manually as follows (pay attention I don't explicitely activate venv) sudo -H -u notifier bash cd /edx/app/notifier/virtualenvs/notifier/bin/python /edx/app/notifier/src/manage.py forums_digest --to_datetime=2018-07-08

Comment: As you can see, posting code in comments is just not useful. Please [edit] your question to provide any additional details or diagnostics.

Comment: If I explicitly set home/cd "$(dirname "/edx/app/notifier")", then everything runs correctly except I get the error sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file nofitier.db
Apparently, it cannot locate the db file which in the folder /edx/app/notifier/db

Comment: If the env was active when you ran `sudo` some settings from it could still be active. Again, please clarify your question by adding the missing details; and if you don't `activate` the env when you should, are you opposed to this as some sort of principle, or did it just not occur to you to try to `activate` within the script?

Comment: sorry, this is my first post on Stackoverflow, no rights to edit posts, yet. Anyways, thanks for a reply.

Comment: explicitly activating the env cd "$(dirname "/edx/app/notifier")" 
source notifier_env source /edx/app/notifier/bin/activate does not help either, I am getting the same error.

Comment: You was right tripleee. Thanks a lot. This now works from the crontab of the user 'notifier'  'code'#!/bin/bash

source /edx/app/notifier/notifier_env
cd /edx/app/notifier/src

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "tomorrow"`

/edx/app/notifier/virtualenvs/notifier/bin/python manage.py forums_digest --to_datetime=$DATE 'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is essentially by the the user **tripleee** (see his replies in the comments above). Indeed, as he suggested, I had to activate venv before running the script. I am just providing the completed steps based on his idea that helped me to solve this problem.
1. This is what I put in the crontab if the user 'notifier'

```
55 13 * * * /edx/app/notifier/not.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

2. And below are contents of the script file not.sh that I created in /edx/app/notifier

```
#!/bin/bash
source /edx/app/notifier/notifier_env
cd /edx/app/notifier/src
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "tomorrow"`
/edx/app/notifier/virtualenvs/notifier/bin/python manage.py forums_digest --to_datetime=$DATE
```